# How to create an animated modal in React.js with 'react-transition-group' for a clickable link trigger?

Tags: reactjs

Modal Closing Problem

Issue: The modal successfully opens in a React.js application with 'react-transition-group', but it lacks the expected behavior of closing when users click outside the modal or press the 'Esc' key. Consequently, users are left trapped within the modal, and there is a noticeable absence of intuitive methods for closing it, which significantly impacts the overall user experience.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: <div className="SvgOptions">
                                <svg onClick={() => setModaiIsOpen(true)} aria-label="Options" className="x1lliihq x1n2onr6" color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)" height="32" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="32"><title>Options</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="6" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle><circle cx="18" cy="12" r="1.5"></circle></svg> <Modal className="Dialog" isOpen={modalIsOpen}>

Comment: <button className="topButton">Block</button>
                                    <button className="middleButtons">Restrict</button>
                                    <button className="middleButtons">Report</button>
                                    <button className="secondLastButton">About This Account</button>
                                    <button class="bottomButton" onClick={() => setModaiIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</button>

                                </Modal>
                            </div>

Comment: const [modalIsOpen, setModaiIsOpen] = useState(false);  // added this before return.